# How to show text in IE only

Tags: html

I need to show text on IE only and not show it for the rest of the browsers. Any pointers to that? I looked around couldn't find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

e.g.

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

(There are operators in the condition for less than, less than or equal, ... and you can chain branches to provider different behaviours for different versions see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) for full details.)

Comment: This answer would be even better with an example code snippet.

Comment: why bother there is snippet on the hyperlink he provided

Comment: Expanded it... and include link to MSDN for the full details.

Comment: So I just put <p> THIS IS IE </p> in the conditional comments?

Comment: Here is my code:   <!--[if lt IE 8]> 
   <p>This game may not display properly on ancient Browsers (IE 6 or lower) please upgrade so you can play the game</p>
  <![endif]-->

http://apps.facebook.com/feline-frenzy/

which does not seem to be working

Comment: Apparently Conditional Comments are not working in Facebook :/

Comment: Doesn't FaceBook have two modes? "You can't write HTML here" and "This is your (application) page loaded in an iframe, everything inside it works as normal"? I don't see why either of those would fail.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that since IE 10 conditional commenting are no longer supported and are treated as regular comments:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

In order for it function as before you need to add the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

There for, for me, if I need to detect IE (although I try to avoid browser detection and use feature detection) I use some code of JS as of here:

[Detect IE version (prior to v9) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript)

Best.

Answer (score 1):

You have IE conditional comments or you can do it via javascript detect browser agents or with javascript frameworks such as jQuery

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
 // do something IE specific
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function detectBrowser(){
        var browser=navigator.appName;
        if (browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
            document.write("IE sux");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: since I'm using Facebook which is pretty much a bitch so I'd have to go with the style sheet. Though this is more cooler ofcourse with the "IE sux" :D

Comment: Please, NO. Let's stop sniffing the User Agent already, especially since IE supports conditional comments. UA is not a reliable way to find out which browser the user is running.

Answer (score 0):

The examples here presume you know javascript.  It would be nice to see everything you need 
if you only know HTML.

e.g.

gobbledegook

Text I only want IE users to see.

moregobbledegook

Answer (score -2):

You need to detect if current browser is IE and show content only in this case.

The smallest script for IE detecting:

```
if(-[1,]) {
   alert("Not IE!");
}
```

Comment: A Javascript bug hack?! Ouch! I hope nobody will actually use this.

Comment: I also hope :) But I think it is an interesting script as it's being the smallest one on this moment for IE detecting.