# How to show different pages for different versions of IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, browser-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Browser detection in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

I was wondering how can I detect IE 6, IE 7 and IE8 and say if any of these show different page instead of index.

Something like update.html would be just fine.

I have seen these IF IE6 and stuff but only for CSS not for index page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<!--[if IE]>
<script language="javascript">
document.location = "http://www.google.com/";
</script>
<![endif]-->
redirects to google if IE
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh quite nice. Thanks :)

Comment: You can use <!--[if IE 6]>, <!--[if IE 7]>, <!--[if IE 8]>, ... to detect version.

Comment: Yeh nice. Thanks man. Ill check as accepted in 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of sources describing how to detect the browser. [Here's the most obvious](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp).

Comment: It is simpler and more reliable to use the IE conditional comments to determine the IE version.

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote? Just because this is not a certain individuals' preferred solution doesn't make it incorrect or bad practice. Reconsider your reason for down voting.

Answer (score 1):

On this page there is one good script that detects IE and its version.

[Detecting Windows Internet Explorer More Effectively (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can detect Browser by jQuery as easy as:

```
jQuery.browser
jQuery.browser.version
```

look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Then check the browser name or version as above, if TRUE then redirect the page to your favorite url:

```
window.location.replace("http://your/address/update.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [$.browser](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser) for easy browser detection.