# Is it possible to use jquery in your code for one browser (eg firefox) but then disable the jquery code for another browser (eg IE10)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css, firefox

I have coded a site that is jquery heavy (animations, css state changes etc) that works perfectly on firefox, but has issues executing the jquery for IE. What I was wondering was is there a way of the jquery code automatically disabling when the site is viewed using IE?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use conditional comments in the head section of your page to include jQuery only for browsers that isn't IE :

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

[conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might use a browser detect plugin, like that:
[Browser detect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html)

For simple purposes, you could use:

```
function isIE () {
  var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
}

if (isIE()) {
    // no jquery
}
```

(from [Detect IE version (prior to v9) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript))