# Execute certain javascript if browser lt ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I want to execute a certain code in jQuery if the browser is lower than IE9. And yes, i already know about

```
<!--[if ... IE ]> <![endif]-->
```

But what i want is to check this condition within the scipt tag and with jQuery document.ready

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //code to check if lt ie9 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect IE version in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript)

Comment: Have you considered using feature detection rather than browser detection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can target older Internet Explorer versions (<= 9) through classes on the `<html>` element...

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html>             <!--<![endif]-->
```

... and then check if `<html>` has the class `.lt9` or `.lt8` — whatever version of Internet Explorer you are targeting:

```
if($('html').hasClass('lte9')) { /* LTE IE9 */ }
```

However, I would suggest using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) feature detection instead of checking for a specific browser.

Comment: This is the most fail-safe and future-proof approach that lends itself to forking for IE both in JavaScript and CSS *and* is treated as HTML comments by all other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use feature detection instead of browser detection. i.e. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Dear _Aegis_, please avoid link only answers, 'cause valuable information will belost when the link is outdated. Instead, give an additional description of your core idea here. Thx!