# Dont run a javascript function in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How to not run a javascript function in IE.I'm having a number of functions in my javascript file..While i need to stop some script from running in Internet explorer.
I know the below code is used to run this script file if not IE..

`<!--[if !IE]><!--><script src="script.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->`

How can i skip some function in js..like below I tried to skip the method b in IE..but it dont work..

```
function a{alert(a);}
<!--[if !IE]>
function b{alert(b);}
<![endif]-->
function c{alert(c);}
function d{alert(d);}
```

but the method b is always called..How can i prevent it from running in IE browsers..

Comment: Put it in it's own script tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect IE version in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript)

Comment: Man, you're in muddy waters ...

Comment: Why modernizer @ShashiBhushan, that it is adding another extra library for something it can work better in pure js ...

Comment: Presumably you want to not run something in IE because it's missing features, or something?  The point of using Modernizr is that instead of targeting a particular browser, you base it on available features - so if there are any other *smaller* browsers that are also missingthose features, then your site doesn't break by making incorrect assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE10 doesn't support conditional comments.

If you don't want to run a function in some browsers, then suppress it with [feature (AKA object) detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html), not user agent detection.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what i do it is a bit nasty, but if there is some functions i don't want to run in  IE I add this ::

```
    <?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') == false)):?>

       <script src="js/noIEfunctions.js"></script>

    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: FWIW, this code will not work in IE11. User-Agent sniffing is evil and should be avoided.

Comment: The IE team took out the MSIE token *explicitly* to break code that was doing foolish User-Agent detection instead of proper capabilities detection. Many webpages work just fine in IE10 or IE11 but due to outdated UA-string checks the pages weren't working. Hence the change.