# IF IE conditional comment in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need to display a text e.g. "You are using Internet Explorer browser" within the div for all users using IE browsers (6-11). MS has dropped conditional comments as of IE10 so I'm unable to do so via css. Any advice?

Comment: Why? IE 10 and 11 are pretty much comparable with other browsers, and versions 6 - 9 can be targeted with conditional comments.

Comment: You could do it the old-fashioned way...check `navigator.userAgent`

Comment: @David Thomas For some unknown reasons IE11 is not uploading attachments via php upload. It's working fine with Chrome and Firefox, but not with IE so I thought it's gonna be quicker for me just to put a warning message for IE users :)

Comment: Quicker for you, kind-of disappointing for your IE users.

Comment: @Pointy Could be just a temporary fix while he digs out the cause of the problem.

Comment: I think it'd be better, long-term, to find out why it's not working, rather than force your users to switch browsers.

Comment: @DavidThomas IE10 and 11 are NOT comparable to other browsers and are still the worst on the planet.

Comment: Feature testing for the particular capabilities you need is a much better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID.userAgent):

```
function isIE () {
  var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if( myNav.indexOf('msie') > -1 || myNav.indexOf('.net') > -1) {
    // do stuff;
  }
}
```

`myNav.indexOf('.net')` is [needed to detect IE 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx), all other versions have `msie` in the UA string.

(modified from code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15983064/1216976))

Answer (score 1):

use ie conditional compilation to target 10/11, which is essentially conditional comments in javascript. you can see a demo here: 
http://dev.bowdenweb.com/ua/browsers/ie/ie10-detection-via-cc.html