# Detect lower versions of Internet Explorer in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I just created mvc 4 application. In that application I want to show alert,if user open this web application using Internet Explorer 6,7 and 8

This is the code I put top of "_Layout.cshtml" file

```
@if ((Request.Browser.Browser == "IE") & ((Request.Browser.Version == "8.0") | (Request.Browser.Version == "7.0") | (Request.Browser.Version == "6.0")))
{
   <script type='text/javascript'>

      alert("You're using older version of Internet Explorer")

  </script>
}
```

But this is not checking internet explorer version , it gives me pop up for almost all  the versions of Internet Explorer ( Edge(11) , 10 , 9 , 8 , 7, 6 )

How can I filter those versions separately

Comment: What is the reason of  doing  this on server side? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-prior-to-v9-in-javascript

Comment: @victork then What is the approach should I take ?

Comment: client size ie version detection. Have you checked the answer by the link I wrote?

Comment: I tried it , seems like not working

Answer (score 3):

**Try this-**

```
  @if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE" && Convert.ToDouble(Request.Browser.Version) < 7.0)
        {   
            <script type='text/javascript'>

                alert("You're using older version of Internet Explorer")

            </script>
        }
```

**Edit-**

This checks if current version of IE is lower than 7.0, You can change the version number accordingly.

**Edit 2-**
I just realized my browser was named as `InternetExplorer`, So I changed following-

```
@if (Request.Browser.Browser == "InternetExplorer" && Convert.ToDouble(Request.Browser.Version) < 7.0)
        {   
            <script type='text/javascript'>

                alert("version is not lower");

            </script>
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting  following error when I put that 

`'string' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertTo' and no extension method 'ConvertTo' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @kez, Check now if it helps you

Comment: when put it its compiled smoothly, but when i deploy it in ie edge getting following error `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format`

Comment: @kez, Check now if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript should do what you need:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "<!--[if lt IE 9]><i></i><![endif]-->";
    var isIeLessThan9 = (div.getElementsByTagName("i").length == 1);
    if (isIeLessThan9) {
        alert("You're using older version of Internet Explorer");
    }
</script>
```