# AjaxToolkit SliderExtender generates JavaScript exceptions in IE11

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using an `ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender` in an `UpdatePanel` like so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSlideshow" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSlideBackgroundOpacity" runat="server"
            ReadOnly="true"
            ToolTip="Adjust the opacity of the background (0 is fully transparent, 100 is fully opaque)"
            OnTextChanged="txtSlideBackgroundOpacity_TextChanged"
            AutoPostBack="true" />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOpacitySlider" runat="server" />
        <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="seSlideBackgroundOpacity" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="txtOpacitySlider"
            BoundControlID="txtSlideBackgroundOpacity" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Works fine in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome, but generates the following exception in IE11:

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value must be an integer.

From [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1913727.aspx?Slider%20control%20JavaScript%20runtime%20error%20Sys%20ArgumentOutOfRangeException%20Value%20must%20be%20an%20integer%20) I looked at compatibility settings, and from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e)
I've tried various combinations of the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="..." />` tag...anything below `IE=11` breaks other things in the site and `IE=11` and `IE=edge` both give me the exception.

I created a clean ASP.NET WebForms project to see if I could isolate the problem, but the slider works in that project, so there's likely some setting in my project that's causing the problem.  Any ideas where I should start looking?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround.  In the debugger I can see what JavaScript is throwing the exception.  So, I use Justin's code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-prior-to-v9-in-javascript) to detect whether the client is IE...if it is, then I do the following:

```
(function () {
    // if we're running internet explorer, we need to fix one of the internal routines to allow for the SliderExtender control to work
    var nIEVersion = internetExplorerVersion();

    if (nIEVersion && nIEVersion <= 11) {
        var originalSetLocation = Sys.UI.DomElement.setLocation;

        Sys.UI.DomElement.setLocation = function (element, x, y) {
            originalSetLocation(element, Math.floor(x), Math.floor(y));
        }
    }
}());
```

It would still be good to know why I'm getting this exception in my production code but not in the clean project, but at least now I'm working.

Comment: John, do you happen to have this set in your web.config?  <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />

Comment: @JeffMergler No. Are you thinking that adding this would fix the problem, or are you thinking that having this might be causing the problem? Thanks.

Comment: John, the presence of the setting caused a problem in my case. When I commented it out in my web.config, the problem disappeared. I don't understand why it's interfering with my slider but I had to remove it to make the slider work in IE11.

Comment: @JeffMergler thanks. I'm not going to sweat this since I found a workaround.

Comment: Fair enough. Note that I reviewed the workaround and the originating SO post and that code snippet failed for me on IE11 (it did not detect IE11, internetExplorerVersion() returned -1) so I wasn't able to detect IE and implement your workaround.  Perhaps you found a reliable way to detect IE11+.